# xml_str2json method returns Null :: Xml to Json Conversion in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, xml

**XML to be converted to json**

```
ns1:UnderwritingRequest xmlns:xsd="" xmlns:xsi="" xmlns:ns1="ABCD" ResponseQueueName="">
  <ns1:Header>
    <ns1:TrackingId>ABCDEF</ns1:TrackingId>
    <ns1:PartnerId>Myhome</ns1:PartnerId>
    <ns1:ProductIdentifier>33</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
    <ns1:ProductRollupId>22</ns1:ProductRollupId>
    <ns1:ProductLoanClass>KYC</ns1:ProductLoanClass>
    <ns1:CustomerId>123</ns1:CustomerId>
  </ns1:Header>
  <ns0:Application xmlns:ns0="ABCDE">
    <ns0:SourceId>Web</ns0:SourceId>
    <ns0:ApplicationNumber>3AAA</ns0:ApplicationNumber>
    <ns0:ApplicationUniqueId>3AAA</ns0:ApplicationUniqueId>
    <ns0:SubmitDate>2015-07-15</ns0:SubmitDate>
    <ns0:OriginalDate>2015-07-15</ns0:OriginalDate>
    <ns0:ExpirationDate>2015-07-25</ns0:ExpirationDate>
    <ns0:InitialSubmitDate>2015-07-15</ns0:InitialSubmitDate>
    <ns0:IsApplicationSigned>true</ns0:IsApplicationSigned>
    <ns0:SignedDate>2015-07-15</ns0:SignedDate>
    <ns0:IsApplicationAccepted>true</ns0:IsApplicationAccepted>
    <ns0:AcceptedAmount>0</ns0:AcceptedAmount>
    <ns0:DecisionType>NO</ns0:DecisionType>
    <ns0:IPAddress>1.1.1.1</ns0:IPAddress>
    <ns0:IsAllFaxesReceived>false</ns0:IsAllFaxesReceived>
    <ns0:Contact>
      <ns0:FirstName>Testzqdp</ns0:FirstName>
      <ns0:LastName>Autozqdp</ns0:LastName>
      <ns0:DateOfBirth>1964-02-25</ns0:DateOfBirth>
      <ns0:SSN>15951</ns0:SSN>
      <ns0:DriversLicenseNumber>HASDFASDF</ns0:DriversLicenseNumber>
      <ns0:DriversLicenseState>TX</ns0:DriversLicenseState>
      <ns0:IsActiveMilitary>false</ns0:IsActiveMilitary>
      <ns0:EMailAddress>test449794@email.com</ns0:EMailAddress>
      <ns0:EMailYears>0</ns0:EMailYears>
      <ns0:EMailMonths>0</ns0:EMailMonths>
      <ns0:HomePhone>9727253097</ns0:HomePhone>
      <ns0:CellPho`enter code here`ne>973097</ns0:CellPhone>
    </ns0:Contact>
```

Fetch Operation in AngularJS

```
var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data.XDocResponse[0]);
```

The i/p parameter contains the xml, but json object comes null, i have iterated through index, other  nodes of xml as well, but no luck.
is there any problem with xml structure?

Please help me as i am stuck from 2 days, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: A little more complete example would help a lot.  Your data plus one line of code doesn't really get it.  How about a ten line code example that gets the data, calls str2json and tries to iterate through the null 'json' variable.  A complete example that everyone can run goes a long way to getting good responses.

Comment: Well, yeah there is a problem with the XML. It's not well formed. But it's hard to tell if you just didn't copy the whole thing in or not. Please start with fixing or clarifying that. Is this really what the response XML is?